# creating a kind of look-up table in c

Tags: c++, arrays, string

here is my code:

```
int month()
  {
      //this array contains all of the months names
       char months[24] = {'JANUARY', 'FEBURARY',  'MARCH ', 'APRIL', 'MAY', 'JUNE',      'JULY',
                 'AUGUST', 'SEPTEMBER', 'OCTOBER', 'NOVEMBER', 'DECEMBER', 'JAN',
                 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEPT', 'OCT', 'NOV',         'DEC'};


       char month_name[10];  // a null terminating char array for your month of birth
       cin >> month_name;

       for(int j = 0; j <= 24; j++ )
           {
             if(month_name == months[j])
           {
              return month_name;
           }
             else
           {
             cout << "\n" << endl;
             show_error();
             cout << "\n" << endl;
             bFlag = false;
             return bFlag;
           }
          }

        }
```

whenever I try to run it I get the message warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion. What does this mean?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What output/error message do you see?

Comment: @MAK judging by the code above, I'm guessing the 'output' he's seeing is a raft of compiler errors, as this code won't even compile, much less *run*.

Comment: "its not working" isn't enough.  We need to know what it is doing and what you expected to do, along with what you've tried in order to fix it.  Posting compilable code is also needed.  If the problem you're having is that your code won't compile, show the code and the **complete** compiler error(s).

Comment: To answer the following portion concretely: "*whenever I try to run it I get the message warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion. What does this mean?*" It means that `'JANUARY'` et al is more data that can be contained in a `char`.

Answer (score 2):

First your month names should be between `"` quotes and make it an array of `char *`

char* months[] = {"january", "feburary",..."december"}

Then, instead of using `==` use `_stricmp` to compare the strings, if the return value is `0`, you have a match.

The `i` in `_stricmp` means to ignore case (so "January" and "january" are considered equals by doing the comparison on lowercase letters), otherwise use `strcmp`

`_stricmp` is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (`stricmp` is deprecated in Visual Studio) but check the comment from mux, I am not familiar with the function but he might be right!

As Nik B. pointed out, you should always return an int. When you find the month return its index (`j`). Seeing how you now added short names for the months, you can keep the correspondence 0 to 11 with january to december by using

```
return j % 12;
```

Comment: ahh, I guess it's _stricmp now?

Comment: sorry, no it's still `stricmp` but it's neither POSIX nor ANSI, I think it's better to use `strcasecmp` :)

Comment: Thanks! Never heard of strcasecmp... but I rarely have to write that kind of code :)

Comment: Also: 'return month_name;' and 'return bFlag'? month_name is a char[10] and bFlag is (apparently) a bool. Your month() function returns an *int*. Do you often put square pegs into round holes?